# javascript continue operator in the for loop

Tags: javascript, continue

Does the "continue" affect performance? For example, what happens if you use it in the bubble sorting function? Would it increase the performance in some cases?

```
    function bubbleSort(array) {

      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        for (let j = 0; j < array.length - i; j++) {

          if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
            [array[j], array[j + 1]] = [array[j + 1], array[j]];
          } else {
            continue;
          }
    
          console.log(array);
        }
      }
    
      return array;
    }
```

Comment: Ignoring `console.log`, in this case, not really. Even if you remove `continue`, there is no line in the loop after the `continue` anyway, so there wouldn't be much difference.

Comment: The general answer to JavaScript performance questions is: Measure your real-world code either way and see whether it makes a difference. Modern JavaScript engines do a **lot** of optimization on "hot" code that's used a lot (and virtually none on code used only once), so naive synthetic tests tend to be misleading. (FWIW, I'd tend to expect that creating and throwing away an unnecessary array -- your element swapping code -- would be more likely to impact the performance of the above than using `continue` -- but measure it and check.)

Comment: @cSharp In the contrary. In this special case if the `console.log` is skipped, it would probably make a huge difference in performance, because outputs (doesn't matter whether it's to a file or into a console) are generally quite expensive. Imagine putting an already sorted array of 100000 elements into this sorter. And now imagine the difference in printing this whole array millions of times vs not even once ...

Comment: Ignoring the console.log if anything this should make it slower as there is a else and in there another command (continue).
I would expect optimizer to handle this. but unless you want the console.log I think it's better to remove unless there is more code you are not showing.
If you want the console.log to be there, or just about any other code, the continue improves performance

Comment: But I'd probably wouldn't use a `else { continue}` for achieving that, but just put the `console.log` inside the `if`'s body. Ie, it will only be executed, if a change happend

Comment: thanks for reply : ) so, the "continue" operator is needed in cases where you want to avoid a large number of "if" conditions? is it the main reason to use it? right?

Comment: what if I would change console.log to for example: document.getElementById("array").innerHTML += array.join(" ") + "<br>";

Comment: @derpirscher exactly why I said "ignoring `console.log`" (assuming `console.log` is just for debugging purposes and not meant to represent the actual algorithm).

Comment: @RomanMaksimov `continue` operator is used to skip **any**, not just `if-else` conditions, on the remaining parts of a loop. I don't think a sorting algorithm is the best example to illustrate the use for `continue` operator.

Comment: @cSharp ok then i misunderstood what you meant by "ignoring". Ie, i undestood that the main purpose of `continue` is to "ignore" the `console.log`,

Answer (score 0):

Continue will skip the `console.log` so you speed up the execution.
You can play with the performance API btw

```js
    const t0 = performance.now();
    bubbleSort([2,9, 3, 89, 100, 5,9,33,66,57,0,9,2,5,66, 4,5,6,3]);
    const t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(t1 - t0, 'milliseconds');
```